# Counting the points below a coordinate

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following problem, for which the solution I use at the moment is too slow.

**Instance:** a numpy array `b` of shape `(B,2)`, a sorted numpy array `x` of shape `(X)`, and a sorted numpy array `y` of shape `(Y)`.

Note that `x = np.unique(b[:,0])` and `y = np.unique(b[:,1])`, if that makes a difference for the problem.

**Task:** Build the `(X,Y)`-array `H` such that `H[i,j]` is the number of rows in `b` whose first entry is less than `x[i]` and whose second entry is less than `y[j]`.

The following example code solves this:

```
import numpy as np
b = np.random.random((2000,2))
x = np.unique(b[:,0])
y = np.unique(b[:,1])
H = np.count_nonzero(
    np.logical_and(
        b[:,0,None,None] <= x[None,:,None], 
        b[:,1,None,None] <= y[None,None,:]
    ), 
    axis=0
)
```

but this gets quite slow if `b` and thus `x` and `y` have a few thousand entries.

How can I do this more efficiently?

Comment: Please give a small example with the desired output (with an explanation on why that output is correct). That will help explain what you're looking for. Also, it's not clear how this relates to `pcolormesh`.

Comment: @jared It's not clear what you're asking for. The code is able to run; to produce the desired output, just run it.

Comment: But is this actually representative? `b` here contains random numbers, so `x` will always be the first row of `b` and `y` the second.

Comment: @jared You meant column, not row, right? Yes, this was also said in the question.

Comment: Sorry, yes, column. And you don't mention anything about them being random. If they are random, why use the `unique` function instead of just sorting them?

Comment: @jared Choosing random values is an example. Of course, I get the values from somewhere else.

Comment: But is it a representative example?

Comment: @jared, Yes, sure! Otherwise, I wouldn't have chosen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Algorithm

Your current implementation is well vectorized but it compute far too much work compared to what can be done. The main issue is that the **algorithmic complexity** of this implementation is **`O(n**3)`**.

This problem can be solved using a **`O(n**2)`** algorithm. This is the **optimal complexity** since `H` needs at least to be filled. The key is to **sort `b`** by `y` so to efficiently count the number of items while computing a row of `H`. The sorted array needs to be **filtered** by `x` so not to care about `x` values in the hot loops. Note that this approach assume that `x` and `y` are sorted, which is the case since `np.unique` sort the values.

---

### Implementation

To improve the performance of the implementation, one can use **Numba** and **multiple threads**. Paying attention to the **memory layout** also matters for the algorithm to be **cache-friendly**.

Here is the final implementation:

```py
import numba as nb

@nb.njit('(float64[::1], float64[::1], float64[:,::1])', parallel=True)
def compute(x, y, b):
    H = np.empty((x.size, y.size), dtype=np.int32)

    # Improve the memory layout
    b_x = b[:,0]
    b_y = b[:,1]

    # Sort both b_x and b_y pairs in a way b_y is sorted
    sorted_idx = np.argsort(b_y)
    sorted_b_x = b_x[sorted_idx]
    sorted_b_y = b_y[sorted_idx]

    for i in nb.prange(x.size):
        # Filter by x
        sorted_filtered_b_y = sorted_b_y[sorted_b_x <= x[i]]

        size = sorted_filtered_b_y.size
        count = 0
        idx = 0

        for j in range(y.size):
            cur_y = y[j]
            while idx < size and sorted_filtered_b_y[idx] <= cur_y:
                count += 1
                idx += 1
            H[i, j] = count

    return H

x = np.unique(b[:,0])
y = np.unique(b[:,1])
compute(x, y, b)
```

---

### Performance Results

Here are performance results on my i5-9600KF machine with the provided input:

```
Naive implementation:    9874.74 ms
This implementation:        3.85 ms
```

Thus, this implementation is **2565 times faster**!

Comment: Wow, this is in amazing speedup. Many things to learn from this!